# unfortunately my first app has stopped with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

I created a new empty android application, containing just a textView.

when I compile it I get unfortunately app has stopped

I looked for the sollution in other topics but none worked.

here is my logcat :

```
04-23 13:07:21.263: W/dalvikvm(1373): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1559 (ActionBarWindow) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
04-23 13:07:21.263: D/dalvikvm(1373): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
04-23 13:07:21.273: D/AndroidRuntime(1373): Shutting down VM
04-23 13:07:21.273: W/dalvikvm(1373): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2abeba8)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373): Process: com.testandro, PID: 1373
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at com.testandro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-23 13:07:21.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1373):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 13:08:20.813: I/Process(1373): Sending signal. PID: 1373 SIG: 9
```

and here is my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testandro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.testandro.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
```

You haven't referenced AppCompat properly. Before referencing you need to have the updated support library. You can download the same from sdk manager under extras.

Check **Adding libraries with resources** @

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: I've made the updates but it still doesn't work, I get the same error, note that I have an old test that works fine. but any new test I create doest

Comment: @FrankelStein AFAIK the steps described in the docs should work. If it does not work it means you are doing it wrong. Other that i have nothing to say